# Import into Eclipse causes error on every line

Tags: java, eclipse, import, buildpath

I have Eclipse on my Windows 8 laptop and on a Windows 7 PC at University. I made some projects at the University and tried to import them at home and there is an error on every single line. It tells me everything cannot be resolved to a type but, as you can see, when I start writing the project from scratch (the second half of the image) I have no such problems.

I apologise, I am new to Eclipse and wonder if anyone can offer any advice. Someone recommended modifying the buildpath settings, I tried to fiddle but could not resolve the problem.

[image: Eclipse Problem]

Comment: What is the strange looking box/square character at the end of the first line in the top aFrame.java? How did you transfer the files?

Comment: When you click the plus sign on the left of that row all of the imports are shown and the box disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing are the default Libraries in your project

Try this:

right-click on the EventHandlingDemo Project -> Build Path -> Add Libraries

then select the "JRE System Library" -> Next -> Finish

that should do it!

Comment: I managed to add the library correctly and then the code wouldn't run after a message popped up informing me the 'main' method couldn't be located. If I start a new project and I copy/paste everything into the new project then no problems...thanks for your help nevertheless.